# Security warning while running signed JNLP file using javaws

Tags: security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, java-web-start

Getting security warning while running signed JNLP file using javaws eventhough Self signed CA is in java trust store.

Below security warning message was displayed.

[image: Security warning-01]

[image: Security warning-02]

Comment: The second message shows two different domain names. Perhaps you need to regenerate the certificate with the right names.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried with the same name but couldn't get positive result. I tried IP address as CN